# Using jQuery Spoiler API to autofocus input

Tags: jquery, html

I using this [jQuery Spoiler on GitHub](https://github.com/le717/jquery-spoiler) and I'm trying to autofucus a input (which is an hidden mobile search bar) while the spoiler content is visible. The Spoiler has it's own API or more 'trigger events' which tried to combined with [this artikel](http://code.runnable.com/UhZDd-HhSAsoAALh/setting-focus-to-an-input-field-using-jquery-for-form). The problem I'm new to jQuery so I don't even know whether the event gets triggered.

Spoiled Content HTML:

```
<div class="flex-col flex-absolut">
    <form id="search-form" action="/" method="get">
        <div class="form-inner">
            <input type="text" name="s" id="search" placeholder="Search..." value="">
            <div class="button-overlay">
                <input type="image" id="button" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Button HTML

```
<li id="menu-item" class="search-toggle spoiler" data-spoiler-link="Q5KQS88F">
        <a class="search-toggle"><?php _e('Search', 'bresponZive');   ?></a>
</li>
```

JS

```
(function($) {

    $(function () { //Equivalent to $(document).ready  
      $(".search-toggle").spoiler({
        // The Spoiler basic setup
        contentClass:           'search-mode',
        spoilerVisibleClass:    'active',
        triggerEvents:          true,
      });

      // Should get triggered and set the autofocus
      jQuery(".search-toggle").on("jq-spoiler-visible", function() {
        $(".flex-col.flex-absolut [name='s']").focus();
      });
    });   

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is no element `.search-toggle` in your provided html

Comment: I forgott the button HTML I'm very sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try use id $("#search").focus();

Comment: Doesn't help hier is my Site, whether it's help https://en.unicstack.com/data/geography-id=11

Comment: $(".search-toggle").on("click", function() {
   $("#search").focus();
});

Comment: I replaced it with this`jQuery(".search-toggle").on("jq-spoiler-visible", function() {
        $(".flex-col.flex-absolut [name='s']").focus();
      });` but it still won't work :(